# Creating an install of Ubuntu to clone

Tags: customization, installation, clone

I work on a team with several other developers.  We all have similar hardware and we all run at least the same base development software.  We are wishing to upgrade from 10.04 to 10.10 doing a clean install.

I am looking for a way to do a base install of Ubuntu, including all our common applications, then clone it to each of the developers drives and then let them further customize their own install.

Some considerations would be giving the developer the ability to have their own person id and not the same as which the base install was done with.  I know they do this on VMware installs and corporate installs of Windows that can then be customized, but I have not seen this done with Ubuntu yet.

Thanks

Comment: As a side note, I found installing using the OEM install path works very well.  When booting Ubuntu, press F4, once at the install menu, press F4 again and select 'OEM install (for manufacturer).  Install as normal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Remastersys to create a bootable ISO of your current install and then install Ubuntu from that ISO on all other machines. All your installed apps will be available by default.

http://www.geekconnection.org/remastersys/ubuntu.html

---

### Important:

Use DIST mode to create the ISO image. Do not use back-up or it will copy your home directory and users too.

Comment: I am unable to open the link you provided

Answer (score 3):

I did this a couple years ago, for 70K+ laptops, on 8.04 I think it was. I set up [Clonezilla SE](http://clonezilla.org/clonezilla-SE.php) server to create the ability to unicast or multicast images. Then, after the Ubuntu installation was perfected, I used oem-config and immediately created the image before logging into the machine again.

Comment: I was not aware that Clonezilla actually has this ability, I will take a look.  thanks for the info.